# Jenkinsfile check if env file exist based on value variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

An environment variable like DISABLE_APPLICATION_NAME is optional. The `APPLICATION_NAME` is the name of the application. Inside our Jenkinsfile we have a loop where the "application name" is stored inside a variable "application_name". I left the loop and other code away, in the example below, but it should be sufficient to give an idea of what I try to accomplish.

I would like to check if the environment variable `DISABLE_<application_name>` exists and is set to TRUE or FALSE.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        DISABLE_APPLICATION_TEST = True
    }
    steps {
        deploy()
    }
}

void deploy() {
    application_name = "APPLICATION_TEST"
    disable_variable = "DISABLE_${application_name}"
    if(env."${disable_variable}"){
        disable = env."${disable_variable}"
    }else{
        disable = False
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but is there any way to check if an environment variable exists, based on the contents of another variable? So like `env["${env_name_stored_in_variable}"]` ?

Comment: `env[env_name_stored_in_variable]` should work fine

Comment: @NoamHelmer I got an error: `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String`. Is there another way besides enabling something?

Comment: Check _Manage Jenkins_ → _**Security**_ → _**In-process Script Approval**_ whether there's something to approve there.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Hmm, unfortunately, I don't have the full access to have "manage jenkins" button.

Comment: whats the pipeline you are actually running? The one in your question is full of syntax errors. You can remove any steps but need to see the structure of your pipeline

Comment: @ErikvandeVen if you don't have permissions you can set the 'DISABLE_APPLICATION_NAME' parameters in your own map (instead of the environment) and use it instead. That map should be defined outside the pipeline directive so it will be available to your functions.